# React Native Video using Mux

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, gorilla, react-native-video, flatlist

Currently I am using the Mux [enter link description here](https://docs.mux.com/)
for video playing inside the flatlist.
Also I had pass the required props for **optimizing** the flatlist.

But in some device video is loading and not giving the exactly user experience like the `instagram`

Any help to improve this performance of the video playing?

**Appreciate your support**